# How to show "External Libraries" node in Android studio like it is shown in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I need to show "external libraries" widget Android studio like it is shown in Intellij.

In Intellij we have:

[image]

but in Android studio for some reason external libraries widget is missing.

[image]

and "select the opened file" button does not work.
How to make it work?

Comment: Version is:

Android Studio 3.6.3
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135, built on April 14, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.3.0-51-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.cursiveclojure.cursive, com.google.services.firebase

And I am loading this project: https://github.com/anolivetree/gradle-clojure-android-sample.

I am not sure if I have time to report a bug. sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio is using the Android view by default for the Project View tool window, you can switch it to the **Project** view to see the same list of dependencies as in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: Dependencies]